# Wi-Fi dropping only on mobile devices

Tags: wifi-configuration

So I’m having a bit of a weird situation and was wondering if someone here could offer some advice. I have three Wi-Fi routers at home, one for each floor with very similar SSIDs (house-ground-floor, house-1st-floor, house-2nd-floor) and all three have 5ghz bands available as well, so add 3 more networks with the same SSIDs with _5g appended to the aforementioned SSIDs.

The problem that I’m facing is my mobile devices, both smartphones and iPad, randomly keep losing connectivity. The issue doesn’t manifest on laptops or my gaming console for instance. And this is consistent behaviour across both android and iOS devices. The fix is usually to just temporarily connect to another Wi-Fi network and it starts working again. Is there anything that I could/should be doing to fix this for good?

TIA for the help!

Comment: What models are the smartphones?

Comment: It's a wide mix. Samsung Galaxy S10, S6 edge, Xiaomi Mi 6, and an iPad

Comment: Try putting all the routers on the same channel and each should have the same ssid (network name)

Comment: Could be just weak Wifi signals. The Wifi antenna on laptops are usually more powerful than on smartphones. When I work at my parents' house with the WIfi router on ground floor and me on the 1st floor, my laptop works fine while my mobile phone's Wifi connection frequently drops.